# HTML form redirects

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need help with following code, I have this form, i want to retrieve a user booking by entering their booking reference and last name, when i click on submit it redirects me to the flight search page instead of view_reservation page. once submit it should go to this with the ref num at the end https://example/bookings/m/view_reservation.aspx?PNR=RefNUM

**javascript:**

```
$("button#jamie").click(function() {
   event.preventDefault();
   var value = $( "#userPNR"  ).val();
   var currentURL = window.location.href;
   var gotto = "https://example.com/bookings/m/view_reservation.aspx?"
   var when = "PNR="
   var goUrl = gotto + when + value;
   window.location = goUrl;
})
```

**html:**

```
<form id="frm_RetrieveReservation" data-ajax="false" rel="external" method="post" action="https://example/bookings/m/view_reservation.aspx?">
   <div id="manager_booking" style="">
       <label>Reservation #</label>
       <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
           <input id="userPNR" name="userPNR" type="text" >
       </div>
       <label>Last Name</label>
       <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
           <input id="passengerName" name="passengerName" type="text">
       </div>
       <button  value="Find Reservation"style="width:96%" class=" ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all Submitters" id="jamie">Search</button>             
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there some JavaScript running on your page? Provide more info.

Comment: sorry i just added the JS script sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'event' parameter to the click handler for event.preventDefault() to function:

```
$("button#jamie").click(function(event) {
```

Comment: that didn't work, still redirects to a different page

Comment: Whats confusing me is the fact that I see the same URL in both your form action and javascript, so how is it redirecting to any other page?

Comment: i don't know its confusing me too been trying to solve this for a while now, friend asked for help on this, don't understand

Comment: There might be another click handler interfering, check the code thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you, for the help i manged to solve it, i created a new form and put the desktop url instead of mobile one